# Decryption in php AES-CBC-128

Tags: php, aes, php-openssl

I was given to use the below credentials to decrypt the incoming source in php:

```
128-bit AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

Secret key (hex): ec313f73c50b8fcb3ecc473107946b358ddf7a04894be9f6eb3bb0781a6d0d2d

IV (hex, initialization vector): 00000000000000000000000000000000

Mode: CBC
```

This is what I tried with the warning error:

```
function decrypt($encrypted_data){
    $ciphering = 'aes-128-cbc';
    $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
    $options = 0;
    $decrypt_iv = '00000000000000000000000000000000';
    $decrypt_key = 'ec313f73c50b8fcb3ecc473107946b358ddf7a04894be9f6eb3bb0781a6d0d2d';
    $decryption = openssl_decrypt($encryption, $ciphering, $decrypt_key, $options, $decrypt_iv);
    return $decryption;
}
```

> Warning: openssl_decrypt(): IV passed is 32 bytes long which is longer
> than the 16 expected by selected cipher

would it require extra conversion for the hex secret key and IV?

Comment: An AES 128 key is exact 16 bytes (or 32 hex string characters) long. Your key is too long so PHP/OpenSSL will cut the other parts of the key off. Are you for sure it is an AES **128** key ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `hex2bin()` to convert the hex-encoded pieces to raw binary.

The cipherText (encrypted data) is likely somehow encoded as well. That's usually done with Base64, but it might be hex too ... apply appropriate decoding there too.

Also, I seriously hope you didn't just share the real encryption key here.